# How to disable this pop-up box when using Deluge BitTorrent Client?

Tags: download-manager, deluge

I find that Deluge BitTorrent Client is faster than most other free BitTorrent download clients so I started using it.

But I somehow, no idea how I did it, enabled a little pop up box when I download stuff.

This box is extremely annoying and I can’t find anything on how to remove it. Any one got any ideas? Or know some other good download managers that aren’t extremely slow?

[image: An image of the box]

Comment: I've been using deluge for a long time and have never seen this dialog.